# Perfect Secrecy and Message distribution

Tags: perfect-secrecy

I have been trying to come up with a proof of the following statement,

Suppose a cryptosystem achieves perfect secrecy for a particular plaintext probability
distribution then Prove that perfect secrecy is maintained for "any" plaintext probability distribution.

Well I know that the perfect secrecy scheme is independent of plaintext distribution, but how to prove the above statement? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which definition are you using for perfect secrecy?

Comment: Shannon Theorem :if |K| = |C| = |P| then the system provides perfect secrecy iff  (1) every key is used with equal probabilify 1/|K|, and     (2) for every x ${\in}$ P and y ${\in}$ C,  there exists a unique key k${ \in}$ K such that $${e_k(x)=y}$$

Comment: so given a ciphertext, an attacker can no find the plaintext.  Pr[p/c]= Pr[p], i.e given a ciphertext probability of a plaintext is same as probability of a plaintext alone. Which is attack can't learn anything from ciphertext about a plaintext.   so, if  one particular plaintext has perfect secrecy (in thoery) then 'any' plaintext has perfect secrecy.

Comment: I tried to use this definition of perfect secrecy: pr(x)=pr(x|y), where $x\in M$ and $y\in C$ @cisnjxqu

Comment: Have you tried formalizing the statement you want to prove?

Comment: that's where I think I am confused. i don't know where to start

Comment: Now using Shannon's Theorem,(as stated above by me), in a different manner.  An encryption scheme satisfy perfect secrecy if for all messages ${m_1},{m_2}$ ,in messages space M, and ciphertext c ${\in}$ C, we have, $${Prob[E(K,m1)=c]= Prob[E(K,m2)=c]}$$.  with both probabilities taken over the choice k (key) in K(keyspace).      Another way of stating this.. for any ${c \in C}$ there exists a constant ${p_c \in [0,1]}$ such that for all ${m \in M}$, we have probability $${Prob[E(K,m1)=c]=p_c}$$

Comment: - In other words, what perfect secrecy requires is that, even a ciphertext, every message is a message space is exactly as likely to be the underlying plaintext. the plaintext is independent of
ciphertext.   -Hence, if our cipher has achieved a perfect secrecy for any message from message space, then cipher provides the perfect secrecy.i.e it uses unique key
to generate  y, irrespective of message m1,m2...

Comment: "for a particular plaintext probability distribution" must be made more precise for the statement to hold. At least, we must exclude probability distributions where some plaintexts have zero probability.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the statement is true, and I will come to a counterexample later.

### Formalization

One possible formalization of the statement could look like this:

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the message space, and $\mathcal{C}$ the ciphertext space.

We define two arbitrary distributions over $\mathcal{M}$: $M_a$ and $M_b$,
where $\Pr_{m \in \mathcal{M}}[M_a = m] = p^\mathcal{M}_a(m)$ and $\Pr_{m \in \mathcal{M}}[M_b = m] = p^\mathcal{M}_b(m)$.

Additionally we need distributions over $\mathcal{C}$: $C_a$ and $C_b$ defined analogously.

An encryption scheme $\Pi = (\mathrm{Gen}, \mathrm{Enc}, \mathrm{Dec})$ is perfectly secret with respect to the distribution defined by $M_a$ if:

$\forall m\in\mathcal{M}, c\in\mathcal{C}. \Pr[M_a=m] = \Pr[M_a = m\ |\ C_a = c]$ and $\Pr[C_a = c] > 0$, to avoid conditioning on an event with zero probability.

We want to show that given $\Pi$ fulfills the above definition, then it also fulfills the same definition with $M_a$ replaced by $M_b$.

### Attempt to Prove

I first attempted (but did not succeed) at proving the statement.
My attempt looks like this:

First show that it suffices to show that the ciphertext distributions are equal
(i.e. that $\Pr[C_a = c] = \Pr[C_b = c]$ holds).

Then show that the ciphertext distributions are equal.

However, I was not able to prove these statements.

### Refutation

I believe I have found a counterexample.

Lets first look at the definition of perfect secrecy:

[image: Definition of Perfect Secrecy (from Introduction to Modern Cryptography by Katz and Lindell]

There are two things I would like to point out:

1. the definition requires independence of the message from the ciphertext for *any* plaintext distribution, so your statement deviates from this requirement.
2. the equation only needs to hold for $\Pr[C = c] > 0$

### Counterexample

Let $\mathcal{M} = \mathcal{C} = \{0,1,2,3\}$.
Further, let our key-space be $\mathcal{K} = \{0,1\}$.

We define an encryption scheme that is perfectly secret for the messages $0$ and $1$, but not for $2$ and $3$:

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{Enc}_k(m) = 
\begin{cases}
k \oplus m & \text{if $m \in \{0,1\}$}\\
m & \text{if $m \in \{2,3\}$}\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Additionally, we define a message distribution as follows:

\begin{equation*}
\Pr[\mathcal{M} = m] = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} & \text{for $m \in\{0,1\}$}\\
0 & \text{for $m \in\{2,3\}$}\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

We now show, that (1) $\Pi$ is perfectly secret with respect to our message distribution.
Then (2) we show that it is not perfectly secret for all message distributions.

1.

We need to show that
$\Pr[M = m] = \Pr[M = m\ |\ C = c]$.

We don't need to show this for $c \in \{2,3\}$ since for our message distribution, $\Pr[C = 2] = \Pr[C = 3] = 0$.

For $c \in \{0, 1\}: \Pr[M = m\ |\ C = c] = \frac{1}{2} = \Pr[M = m]$.

Therefore, the encryption scheme is perfectly secret for the given message distribution.

2.

However, given a message distribution that assigns $2$ or $3$ a non-zero probability, the scheme is trivially not perfectly secret:

$\Pr[M = 2] \neq 0 = \Pr[M = 2\ |\ C = 3]$

Therefore the scheme is not perfectly secret for all message distributions, and thus the statement does not hold in general.

## Appendix

For completeness here is the decryption algorithm:

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{Dec}_k(c) =
\begin{cases}
c \oplus k & \text{if $c \in \{0,1\}$}\\
c & \text{if $c \in \{2,3\}$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

and the key generation:

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{Gen}() = k \stackrel{sample}{\leftarrow}\{0,1\}
\end{equation*}

Comment: what is the value of $k \oplus m$? Is it 0 or 1? Then your keyspace is already short than the message space, if not it may already be insecure.

Comment: Lemma 1: An encryption scheme (Gen, Enc, Dec) over a message space M is perfectly secret if and only if for every probability distribution
over M, every ${m_0, m_1 \in M}$, and every ciphertext ${c \in C}$    $${Pr[C=c|M=m_0]}=Pr[C=c|M=m_1]$$


By Lemma 1:for any ${m_i,m_j \in M}$   $${Pr[K=k_i]=Pr[Enc_k(m_i)=c]=Pr[Enc_k(m_j)=c]=Pr[K=k_j]}$$
Since ${k_i \neq k_j for i \neq j}$, this mean each key is chosen with probability 1/|K|

Comment: @kelalaka yes $k \oplus m \in \{0,1\}$. Yes this encryption scheme is not perfectly secret with respect to all message distributions, but it is perfectly secret with regards to message distributions that only assign $0$ and $1$ a non-zero probability.

Comment: @SSA Yes, the key is chosen uniformly random

Comment: But original statement is " Suppose a cryptosystem achieves perfect secrecy for a particular plaintext probability distribution p0. Prove that perfect secrecy is maintained for any plaintext probability distribution." and it is true. because if perfect secrecy is proved for any message ${m_i}$ then probability of any ciphertext ${c \in C} $ equally possible for any message ${m \in M}$  because of random probability of a chosen key i.e. ${\frac{1}{|K|}}$.  why do you think it is not correct?

Comment: Please review the counterexample to the statement within my answer.

Comment: if we have random variable m over ${\{0,1}\}^n$  and k independent uniform variable on ${\{0,1}\}^n$  
then c= m xor k is uniform random variable over ${\{0,1}\}^n$, irrespective of what m is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116874/discussion-between-cisnjxqu-and-ssa).

Answer (score 0):

Proof:
$${Pr[Y=y]=  \sum_{K \in Z_{26}} Pr[K=k]   Pr[x=d_k(y)]   }$$
$$ =\frac{1}{26}{\sum_{K \in Z_{26}} Pr[x=y-K]}$$
$$={\frac{1}{26}}$$
Hence,
$${Pr [y|x] = Pr[K=(y-x) mod 26] }$$
$$={\frac{1}{26}}$$

Above equation shows that For every pair of yand x there is exactly one key, and probability of that key is 1/26. i.e.,
$${Pr (x|y) = Pr(x) }$$

Comment: You have assumed here $|M|=|K|$, what if $|K|\ge |M|$? \\ How can we say that if  $|K|\ge |M|$ we will still have $Pr[K=k]=\frac{1}{K}$